# Como puedo manipular los datos un Json que me manda mi back end para pintar distintos datos de varios colores?

Tags: html, json, angular

Estoy recibiendo un servicio de un JSON, en el cual hay un atributo que se llama PalClav, este contiene Idioma y coincidencias con ese idioma, lo que necesito es que el atributo Idioma lo pueda pintar de color azul.  [image: asi es como se muestra y lo estoy pintando actualmente]

Estoy usando angular para imprimir los datos y este es el codigo donde mando llamar ese atributo  <p [innerHTML]='articulo.palClave'>{{articulo.palClave}}

y al final se imprime de esta manera en html, estoy usando el InnerHTML por que ya trae codigo html en el json. Sin embargo no me pueden enviar el idioma de color azul como yo lo quiero.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy ambigua, no se entiende que es lo que tienes y que deseas hacer, si puedes publicar algo de código y explicar mas el problema, asi podemos tener un mejor panorama y ver en que se te puede apoyar

Comment: Listo! Una disculpa

Comment: ¿Hay algún identificador dentro de la propiedad del JSON qué se puede utilizar para identificar las palabras que deben ser marcadas de otro color?